# Characteristic polynomial for this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question is from Artin's Algebra:

> Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $(v_0,\ldots, v_n)$ and let $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ be scalars. Define a linear operator $T$ on $V$ by rules $T(v_i)=v_{i+1}$ if $i<n$ and $T(v_n)=a_0v_0+\ldots+a_nv_n$. Determine the matrix $T$ with respect to the given basis, and the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

I think the required matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &a_0 \\
 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &a_1 \\
 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 &a_2 \\
 \vdots  & \vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1& a_n    
 \end{pmatrix}$$ How to compute characterstic polynomial?

Comment: Do a cofactor expansion method on the last column.

Comment: @dezdichado You mean if matrix I wrote is $A$, then to find determinant of $tI-A$, I should focus on last column of $tI-A$?

Comment: This is a companion matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is $P(\lambda)=a_0+a_1\lambda+\cdots+a_n\lambda^n$

Comment: @Silent, yes that should do it.